# Detect if a Windows filesystem supports built-in file compression?

Tags: windows, filesystems, compression

Windows NTFS supports built-in folder and file level compression. Windows FAT does not.

([And there are others](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison#compression) which fall into one of those two categories as well.)

**How can you detect whether or not the filesystem has this capability?**

**Scenario:** need to script some activities and would like to set certain files to be compressed if that is possible. But if it is not the script can't fail; so ideally I'd like to check for this first. So the best case is finding a straightforward command line approach to check for compression capabilities.

---

**Note/Related:** According to [Is there a way to toggle the Windows "compress this drive" command through a command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/1069033/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-the-windows-compress-this-drive-command-through-a-com) you can use the `compact` utility to actually de/compress files & folders on a filesystem which supports that. Would this even exist on a Windows PC installed to a FAT filesystem? If so, what will happen if you run it? (I don't have an example PC to try it on.)

---

**Note:**  Seems like [there is a programmatic way to do this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa#remarks), but as mentioned that is not really the best approach for a scripting application.

Comment: If .NET framework is installed on all PC's, you might be better served by using Zip in script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-script-using-only-windows-built-in-capabiliti

Comment: "Would this even exist on a Windows PC installed to a FAT filesystem?" - Windows hasn't support being installed to a FAT filesystem in while.  Why are you worried about this edge case?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks; the reason for looking into filesystem compression is to be able to leave files compressed which can then still be used by preexisting programs.

Comment: @Ramhound that's a fair point; but we do have some users who still use older PCs and I'd like to not break anything for those cases.

Comment: @DaveInCaz - When I say awhile I am talking about Windows 98 and earlier.  The default for Windows XP was always NTFS.  Which means if your users have a Windows installation, installed on a FAT partition, it means they are an operating released 2 decades ago.

Comment: @Ramhound it was XP I was thinking of... but you may be right that cases where it would be installed to FAT might be very rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect whether or not the filesystem has compression capability one can use utility that included with Windows `fsutil`, the only thing you need to keep in mind is that `fsutil` requires administrative rights. You can detect  the filesystem's directly:

```
fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo c: | find "File System Name"
```

that will return file system name.

If you need to detect compression support only, then you can run following code:

```
fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo c: | find "Supports file-based Compression"
```

which disclose the specific detail you needed.

Also by inspecting the full output of `fsutil` one can get more details regarding file system in question (that would looks like):

```
Volume Name : VolumeLabel
Volume Serial Number : 0x01020304
Max Component Length : 255
File System Name : NTFS
Supports Case-sensitive filenames
Preserves Case of filenames
Supports Unicode in filenames
Preserves & Enforces ACL's
Supports file-based Compression
Supports Disk Quotas
Supports Sparse files
Supports Reparse Points
Supports Object Identifiers
Supports Encrypted File System
Supports Named Streams
Supports Transactions
Supports Hard Links
Supports Extended Attributes
Supports Open By FileID
Supports USN Journal
```

AFAIR `fsutil` is included at least since Windows XP

> ... you can use the compact utility to actually de/compress files & folders on a filesystem which supports that. Would this even exist on a Windows PC installed to a FAT filesystem? If so, what will happen if you run it?

`compact` utility is present in Windows XP even if it installed on FAT, but will return ERRORLEVEL code greater than zero when one would attempt to run it on FAT. I believe it kept because Windows XP supports conversion of FAT filesystem to NTFS on live systems, so it can be used in a future.

Comment: `compact` is needed to support all NTFS volumes, not just the boot volume but even removable volumes.